# Access Session variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, razor

I wanted to access a session variable in javascript in asp.net mvc application. I have found a way to do it in aspx view engine but not in razor.

Please tell me a way to access the session variables

Comment: Have you tried adding the session value to a model?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it this way for a `String` variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someSessionVariable = '@Session["SomeSessionVariable"]';
</script>
```

Or like this if it's numeric:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someSessionVariable = @Session["SomeSessionVariable"];
</script>
```

This is really not a very clean approach though, and requires inline JavaScript rather than using script files. Be careful not to get carried away with this.

Answer (score 8):

I personally like the data attribute pattern.

In your Razor code:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-value="@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["someKey"]"></div>
```

In your javascript:

```
var value = $("#myDiv").data('value');
```

Comment: How can I access and get the value of this session from my Controller?

Comment: In any MVC or Web API controller, you can just type `var myValue = Session["MyKey"];` to get the value for "MyKey"

Answer (score 1):

In my asp.net I am not getting the result by

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          var someSessionVariable = '@Session["SomeSessionVariable"]';
     </script>
```

But I get the answer by below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     var yourVariable = '<%= Session["SessionKey"] %>';

</script>
```

Comment: I think, you haven't used MVC in your application.

Answer (score 0):

**For google searchers,**

In addition, If you want to access the session variable in external `.js` file you can simply do like this,

```
------ SOME HTML PAGE ------

//Scripts below Html page
<script>   
    //Variable you want to access
    var mySessionVariable = '@Session["mySessionVariable"]';
</script>

// Load External Javascript file
<script src="~/scripts/MyScripts/NewFile.js"></script>
```

Inside **`NewFile.js`**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(mySessionVariable);
});
```