# Accessing class variables that are stored in Session State with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session-variables, session-state

I have a class that is stored in my Session State in my asp.net project. I can access this without issue on the server side.

However I would like to be able to access properties of my class via javascript.

I have used the below when accessing a simple variable:

```
<%= Session["UserName"] %>
```

However I would like to be able to do something like:

`<%= Session["Person.Name"] %>`

when I have stored the Person class in my Session State. Is this possible?

Comment: Check here 

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972880/access-session-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `Session` internally stores a collection of `object`s, you'll need to cast the value back to a `Person` first, e.g.:

```
<% = (Session["Person"] as Person).Name %>
```

You could also look at a generic helper, e.g.

```
public T SessionGet<T>(string key)
{
    object value = Session[key]; // or HttpContext.Current.Session
    if (value != null)
    {
        return (T)value;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

And use like so:

```
<% = SessionGet<Person>("Person").Name %>
```