# A button that redirects you to pages depending on your status

Tags: javascript, c#

The code in question is in **C#**, since I can't use a `<form>` tag on my masterpage, I will need to "convert" is to JS. problem is - I'm only a beginner in JS. Any tips can help. The code:

```
if (Request.Form["button"] != null && Session["is_logged"] != null && Session["Admin_or_nah"] != null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("juss_tryin.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        if (Request.Form["button"] != null && Session["is_logged"] != null && Session["Admin_or_nah"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("UserData.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }
```

the `Request.Form["button"] != null` acts like "if I click the button"... this part is taken care of because of the `onclick` setting.

I'll use `window.location.href = "page.aspx";` for redirecting.

the 2 other sections are for session variables - these ones I don't know how to code. I'm having trouble integrating the session variables into JS, and all..

**EDIT:**
*I've coded this:*

```js
    var is_logged = '@Session["is_logged"]';
    var Admin_or_nah = '@Session["Admin_or_nah"]';

    function redirectFunction() {
        if (is_logged != null && Admin_or_nah != null) {
            window.location.href = "juss_tryin.aspx";
        } else {
            if (is_logged != null && Admin_or_nah == null) {
                window.location.href = "UserData.aspx";
            } else {
                window.location.href = "Login.aspx";
        }
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work though. just redirects me to "juss_tryin.aspx" all the time. Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**
*another try:*

```js
    var is_logged = '@Session["is_logged"]';
var Admin_or_nah = '@Session["Admin_or_nah"]';

function redirectFunction() {
    if (is_logged.length < 1 && Admin_or_nah.length < 1) {
        window.location.href = "juss_tryin.aspx";
    } else {
        if (is_logged.length < 1 && Admin_or_nah.length >= 1) {
            window.location.href = "UserData.aspx";
        } else {
            window.location.href = "Login.aspx";
    }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work though. this time, it redirects me to "Login.aspx" all the time.

Comment: JavaScript generally doesn't have access to session state, since it's a web server concern. If you must, you can share it by setting a `data-` attribute on an easy-to-access HTML element (e.g., `body` or `html`), or a hidden field, to that session variable, then get that value via JavaScript.

Comment: can you give me an example using the variables in the code so I'll have a better idea of what to do?

Comment: See [Access Session variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20972880/215552)

Comment: ok... I'll work with that. I hope I'll get the `if()`s right

Comment: @HereticMonkey tried it... didn't work out very well. I've edited the post.

Comment: Well, those will never be null, because you've wrapped them in quotes, so if `Session["is_logged"]` is null, `is_logged` will be `''` (i.e., the empty string).

Comment: I see. then maybe I can redirect based on the number of letters or something like that.

Comment: tried it.. doesn't work - now it redirects me to the "Login.aspx" page :""D

Comment: @HereticMonkey is there anything wrong with my second try?

Comment: I'd do `console.log(is_logged)` after you set it and see what's logged in your console. It might be set to the string `'null'` rather than empty string?

Comment: @HereticMonkey could be! didn't think about that! will check.

Comment: @HereticMonkey so, I tried like the first time, but with a pair of ' ' around every `null`, it now just redirects me to "juss_tryin.aspx" again... which leads me to believe that it was an empty string... I don't know how to use `console.log` btw ;^)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just making a Redirect.aspx page, it may not seem elegant, but it's instantaneous and really nice.